# How do I decorate an __init__ method with Click?

Tags: python, python-click

I frequently use the following pattern, where I create an instance of a Main object, typically for a batch, then call `process()` on it.  All the necessary options are passed into the `__init__`.  This means that, provided I create a Main with the appropriate parameters, I can run it from anywhere (**celery** being an example).

(I have learned to minimize in-celery debugging to the greatest extent to keep my sanity - the scripts are debugged fully from the command line first, and only then are Mains created and launched from celery)

#### This is my working **Click** approach:

Pretty simple.  the decorated `run` function defines its arguments and passes them to `Main.__init__`.

Conceptually however, `run` and its docstring are very separated from that `__init__`.  So on the `__init__` I have to look at `run` to understand what to pass and when I `--help` the command line, I get the docstring for `run`.

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('--anoption')
def run(**kwargs):
    mgr = Main(**kwargs)
    mgr.process()

class Main:

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(**kwargs)

    def process(self):
        print(f"{self}.process({vars(self)})")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

#### output:

```
<__main__.Main object at 0x10d5e42b0>.process({'anoption': None})
```

#### This is what I would like instead:

```
import click

class Main:

    @click.command()
    @click.option('--anoption')
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(**kwargs)

    def process(self):
        print(f"{self}.process({vars(self)})")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = Main(standalone_mode=False)
    main.process()
```

But that gets me `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

#### Using a `factory` method

the closest I've come is with a factory staticmethod, but that's not great.  At least the factory is sitting on the class, but there's still not much of a link to the **init**.

```
import click

class Main:

    @staticmethod
    @click.command()
    @click.option('--anoption')
    def factory(**kwargs):
        return Main(**kwargs)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(**kwargs)

    def process(self):
        print(f"{self}.process({vars(self)})")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = Main.factory(standalone_mode=False)
    main.process()
```

#### output:

```
<__main__.Main object at 0x10ef59128>.process({'anoption': None})
```

What's a simple Pythonic way to bring `click` and that `Main.__init__` closer together?

Comment: That `Main` class is pointless. This isn't Java. You don't need to wrap every action in an object. You can write functions.

Comment: If you're asking for the Pythonic way, the Pythonic way is to get rid of `Main`.

Comment: I am well aware Python <> Java.  But I do want to separate the setting up of parameters from the immediate execution of the function.  To me that means a class.  Maybe you have other ideas, that's fine, but that's **not** what I am asking.   If it is **not possible** then I do welcome that insight. What I am doing works just fine for its purposes, and I am not saying it's best practices overall.  Or do you have another suggestion to put say Click and Celery together?  Because that is the core motivation here.

Comment: What I want to do here via click, because command line, is akin to the Command Pattern.  i.e. create an object with necessary parameters, then run it.

Comment: So, you're essentially trying to get a lazy initialization of an object but defer execution until called explicitly?

Comment: The object is explicitly instantiated.  The idea is really to adapt a batch program for use by other programs, such as celery tasks or even calling from generic application code.   Click, and before that, argparse/optparse, decorate a function to create an object with execution parameters.  All the “brains” are kept in the `process` so complex code is debugged from cli and unittests.  Then an introspection mechanism generates html forms from the click decoration and feeds the appropriate `**kwargs` to `Main.__init__` when prepping a Celery task.

Comment: By using a class a lot of the auxiliary behavior around these processes can be inherited as well. For example, a number of these processes depend on each other so have code in place to check and stop with an error if their predecessors haven’t been run.

Comment: I am still not understanding why decorating the `__init__` with the click details, is considered "more" useful that decorating your factory function.

Comment: Why not just call your factory function `cli()`?  Then the introspection and machinery is as it was for `__init__`.

Comment: well, I can rename the factory function, but really, what somewhat bothers me is that, when I look at `__init__` I don't really know what it expects, I have to look at the factory function to know that.  It's not a big deal, but...  Also, I was just plain curious to see if anyone knew how to wire up **Click** to methods rather functions.